# Text passes element width

Tags: css, laravel, notifications, bootstrap-4

I am trying to do show some notifications here, but the notification text passes the element width, I want the text to go to the next line if it's too large

[image]

I am using the Dropdowns from Bootstrap to do the notifications.

Comment: Can you create a snippet with your `html` and `css`?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, sorry.
I am using the dromdown from bootstrap so that's bassically the css. I only added overflow-y:auto; to supposedly to show the vertical scroll in case there were too many

Comment: The problem is, I tried making text really long within a dropdown on Bootstrap docs page and it does not behave the same. Dropdown stretches to fit text, or text overflows. There is never a scrollbar.

Comment: Added a max-width:25vw; and max-height:50vh;

Comment: I don't want this to sound mean but you need to learn to create snippets on SO. It's just part of the deal, we need to see your code.

Comment: No problem, I get it. I'll check them out

Comment: Ping me again when you do, I'll be glad to help.

Comment: Someone already replied a solution that worked for me, but I will definitely check about the snippets to make it easier for you guys. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap sets `white-space: nowrap` in its style sheets.

To get word wrap you need to change it to eg. `normal` in your css.

More abut white-space property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Bellow simple code snippet based on examples from Bootstrap site.

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  width: 150px;
}

.wordwrap {
  white-space: normal !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown button
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Text wihout any css</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item wordwrap" href="#">Text with white-space set to normal</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```